# экспорт отчета access 2013 в excel

Tags: ms-access

при экспорте отчета из access 2013 в excel пропадают поля с данными из области "примечание группы", при экспорте отчета в .rtf все поля на месте

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: экспортируются все поля, кроме тех которые находятся в области "примечание группы"

Comment: Экспорт в Эксель реализован не очень хорошо, не все элементы экспортируются как ожидается. Лучше руками создавать шаблон со всем форматированием и формулами и уже туда вставлять основные данные из базы, тогда будет ожидаемый результат. Примеров реализации много в Интернете.

Comment: вопрос: почему 1 поле экспортируется (выделено красным), а остальные нет (выделено синим)

Comment: Я уже ответил почему: Экспорт в Эксель реализован не очень хорошо